# How to re-prompt and re-use a user's input

Tags: ruby, loops, prompt

I was trying to re-prompt a user's input and reuse it. Here's the code sample:

```
print "Please put your string here!"

user_input = gets.chomp
user_input.downcase!

if user_input.include? "s"
  user_input.gsub!(/s/,"th")
elsif user_input.include? ""
  user_input = gets.chomp
  puts "You didn't enter anything!Please type in something."
  user_input = gets.chomp
else
  print "no \"S\" in the string"
end
puts "transformed string: #{user_input}!"
```

My `elsif` will let the user know that their input was not acceptable, but was not effective in re-using their input to start from the beginning. How am I supposed to do it? Should I use a `while` or `for` loop?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but for any string `s`, `s.include? ""` is `true`.

Comment: @sawa, of course you don't know because you've not asked him.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this solves your problem :)

```
while true
  print 'Please put your string here!'
  user_input = gets.strip.downcase

  case user_input
    when ''
      next
    when /s/
      user_input.gsub!(/s/, "th")
      puts "transformed string: #{user_input}!"
      break
    else
      puts "no \"S\" in the string"
      break
  end
end
```

Comment: HI thank you so much! It works! I just have one question about the `next` method. Does it mean to skip the above condition and starts from the top? Instead of going to the second condition?

Comment: Yes, 'next' skip rest of the code from the current iteration and start the next iteration.

Comment: The `next` can be omitted, if desired.

Comment: right you are @WayneConrad as there is no other statement after the case

Answer (score 0):

You can have a loop at the beginning to continuously ask for input until it's valid.

```
while user_input.include? "" #not sure what this condition is meant to be, but I took it from your if block
    user_input = gets.chomp
    user_input.downcase!
end
```

This will continuously ask for input until `user_input.include? ""` returns false. This way, you don't have to validate input later.

However, I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. If you want to re-prompt when the input is *empty*, you can just use the condition `user_input == ""`.

**EDIT**: [Here's the doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-include-3F) for `String.include?`. I tried running `.include? ""` and I get `true` for both empty and non-empty input. This means that this will *always* evaluate to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  user_input = nil    
  loop do
      print "Please put your string here!"
      user_input = gets.chomp
      break if user_input.length>0
  end
  user_input.downcase!
  if user_input.include? "s"
     user_input.gsub!(/s/,"th")      
  else
     puts "no \"S\" in the string"
  end

  puts "transformed string: #{user_input}!"
```

Comment: Blocks of code don't look ok without any explanations. Consider adding some

Comment: i just change the looping part with "loop do". first, i use "loop do" because i initiate user_input with nill value so "loop do" still execute once. it will loop until the user enter one or more input, the rest is same