# What can't I redact certain words by using this ruby code?

Tags: ruby, loops

I"m learning ruby on codecademy and I'm struggling with some ruby loop/iteration codes. This is not a duplication of [How to re-prompt and re-use a user's input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34971716/how-to-re-prompt-and-re-use-a-users-input), because I didn't want to ask how to reprompt the user's input, but how to print out the redacted output. Below is the code example and the codes meant to change/redact certain words in the user's input:

```
puts "Please enter the text"
text = gets.chomp
text.downcase!
words = text.split(" ")
#ask for user input and turn the input into an array

puts "Please enter the redact word"
redact = gets.chomp
redact.downcase!
redacts = redact.split(" ")
#ask the user what words they want to redact in their input

words.each do |word|
if word == redacts.[i]
  word = "REDACTED "
else
  word = word
end

print word + " "
end
#print out the redacted input (including irredacted and redacted words)
```

But this code doesn't seem to work...I'm not sure why...Can you help me on this? Thank you!

Comment: This is not a duplicated question. I mean the two codes in these 2 questions are similar, but I tried to do different things. First is to reprompt the user input, the second is to generate the output I want...Please take a look and let me know. Thanks!

Comment: If my answer solved your problem could you please tick this as the accepted answer for the benefit of future users who might be experiencing the same problem?

Comment: Hi Par, oh I voted yours, but forgot to tick it. Here you go. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following version:
I am looping through all the redacted words and removing them from the input words array

```
puts "Please enter the text"
text = gets.chomp
text.downcase!
words = text.split(" ")
#ask for user input and turn the input into an array

puts "Please enter the redact word"
redact = gets.chomp
redact.downcase!
redacts = redact.split(" ")
#ask the user what words they want to redact in their input

redacts.each do |redact|
    words.delete(redact)
end
#print out the redacted input (including irredacted and redacted words)
print(words.join(" "))
```